# Best way to find if there is a one-typo word from list of given words

Tags: string, algorithm, list, matching

How would you efficiently solve this problem

Suppose we were given a list of words [“apple”, “banana”, “mango”]

If we are given a word in the list that is one typo away,
“Dpple”
“Adple”
“Appld”
We output true

If there is more than one typo, we output false.

For optimizations, I’ve tried storing the list in a hashtable containing the number of letters of each word and looking for the same number of letters upon the given input to reduce the size in which we look for our input. Is there a faster optimization we can make to this problem?

Comment: you can use a *prefix*-tree, and slightly change the algorithm such that it works in a dynamic programming matter with references to several parts of the tree.

Comment: Or you can have a trie datastructure. If you encounter one mismatch, you still traverse to the next level and look for matches. You stop when you encounter more than one mismatch. Complexity should be about 26 * N for each word.

Comment: storing number of letters of each word is not an option, it's going to treat all permutations as correct. for example it will treat "ananab" and "banana" as same

Comment: Will the list change frequently, or it is a fixed list?

Answer (score 0):

One possible optimisation would be to generate all one-typo words for the given list and put them in a map (or some better string lookup structure). Then lookup the given words - if found output `true`, else `false`. The total number of one-typo words is: `25*L`, where `L` is the total number of letters in the input list (assuming case does not matter).